# How to include -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809 when you compile the code

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am doing an assignment which states: "The skeleton code given uses `getopt`. If you compile the code with `-std=c99`, there will be compilation
error. To fix the error, include `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809` when you compile the code."

I am very new to this. Ordinarily I compile a C program with GCC (program name) and then I type `./a.out.`

What am I required to do here?

Comment: Add the suggested option to your command line for compiling. And, please, get used to read documentation.

Comment: You have been given a code that uses `getopt()`, which is a non-standard funciton and the assignment is telling you to compile adding that flag to make it available. So instead of `gcc -std=c99 prog.c` just do `gcc -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809 prog.c`

Comment: It means you should change the compile line from `gcc program.c` to `GCC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809 program.c`.  Or don't use `-std=c99`; or use `-std=gnu99`; or use 11 in place of 99.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect as in the answers already provided (`gcc ... -D...`) by defining the macro at the very very top of your file(s), before any standard include, before header guards, ... at line 0: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809`

Answer (score 2):

The sentence “To fix the error, include `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809` when you compile the code” means to include the characters `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809` in the command you use to compile the program.

For example, if you normally use `gcc -o foo foo.c`, change it to `gcc -o foo -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809 foo.c`.

This is a command line argument that tells the compiler to define a preprocessor macro named `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be replaced by `200809`. This preprocessor macro is used by various header files to adapt to different versions of POSIX (by using `#if` statements to test the macro). For example, if you specify `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be `200809` or leave it undefined, the headers will not declare routines that were only added to POSIX after the 2008-09 version of POSIX. Among other things, this avoids causing conflicts with programs written before then that might have happened to use names of those routines for other purposes (since they would have had no way of knowing what names POSIX header would define in the future).

You can also define the macro in your source code, before any headers that use it are included, with:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getopt` function is a relatively recent addition to the Single UNIX Specification/POSIX Standard.  While Linux doesn't comply with POSIX, it does roughly use this standard as a reference point.  However, it's mostly implementing XSH (System Headers) of POSIX '03 or earlier **by default** for compatibility.  If you want more recent additions exposed (Note: @JonathanLeffler mentions that getopt is there for quite some time already, but Linux doesn't expose it by default anyway), you can tell the GNU libc (the C Library commonly used on GNU/Linux systems) to also provide some of that functionality which are hidden behind **Feature Test Macros**.  Lookup the man-page `man -s 7 feature_test_macros` [2](https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros) in combination with `man -s 3 getopt` [1](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) for more.  Basically, in the respective headers there's some code similar to the following:

```
#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
/* declaration of getopt() and other newer functions */
#endif
```

If you then include that file and do not define the feature test macro to have a value greater than (newer/more recent than) the date of that POSIX standard you need (2008-09), the C Preprocessor will throw away all those forward declarations, making your code error out.

Using `-DFOO=bar` you `#define FOO bar` on the command line for the standard C Compiler.  By the way, the GNU C Compiler also sets some of such flags when you use `-std=c99`.

In the end, your command line should look more or less like this:

```
$ c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -o foo foo.c
```

This will compile and link `foo.c` to the output file `foo` adhering to the C99 standard and using features from POSIX '08 [3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html).

Comment: POSIX has specified `getopt()` for a very long time (1992 or earlier).  Using `-std=c99` means that most of the extensions in POSIX over C99 are disabled and have to be explicitly activated.  Note that using `-std=gnu99` activates POSIX and GNU/Linux extensions as well as the C99 standard support.

Comment: True, it's been there for a long time, but yet isn't enabled by default in Linux, even when using `-std=c17` as this flag (mostly) impacts the compiler and the C standard behavior, not POSIX or library features outside of what the C standard mandates.

Comment: Because it is not Standard C.  Using `-std=c17` says "use the semantics of C17 and do not enable anything else (such as POSIX, or `_GNU_SOURCE` or …)".  Using `-std=cXY` says "I want standard C only — no extensions unless I request them separately".  Of course, GCC being GCC, you have to add `-pedantic` to shut off all GCC extensions, but the vast majority of O/S features and POSIX features are disabled by use `-std=cXY` instead of `-std=gnuXY`.

Comment: Why go on and on with discussion and leave the information the question asked about (put the switch in the command line) to the end? The question does not ask why the switch is needed, just how to give it to the compiler. Put the primary answer first. Supplementary information can go after.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but whether the flag is defined or not doesn't depend on the C standard, that seemed unclear

Comment: @EricPostpischil I prefer to lead to an answer and explain it rather than "just" give the solution as people do not learn why. Possibly personal preference.